# Size of Circular Queue

Tags: algorithm-analysis, data-structures, queues

I am Implementing a Queue using circular arrays in C language .The Implementation uses one empty position to indicate that the queue is full.That is if the rear is two position behind front. The condition is we cant use a variable to count the entries in the queue as we insert or delete . I have created this function to find the size of queue with Time Complexity Big-Oh(n) because it starts with front and goes upto rear in a loop .

```
int QueueSize(Queue *q)
{
    if(QueueEmpty(q))
    {
        return 0;
    }
    else{
        int count=0;
    for(int i=q->front;;i=(i+1)%MAXQUEUE)
    {
        count++;
        if(i==q->rear) break;
    }
        return count;
}
}
```

Is there a way to find the size of queue in constant time ?
Elements are inserted from rear and deleted from front !
My Queue starts from 0 and assume maximum queue size is 6 in below example

```
10 Appended at position 0
20 Appended at position 1
30 Appended at position 2
40 Appended at position 3
50 Appended at position 4
10 Removed from position 0
20 Removed from position 1
60 Appended at position 5
70 Appended at position 0
30 Removed from position 2
40 Removed from position 3
80 Appended at position 1
90 Appended at position 2
Queue Size:5
Position:4  Element:50 (front)
Position:5  Element:60
Position:0  Element:70
Position:1  Element:80
Position:2  Element:90 (rear)
```

Comment: This seems to be very implementation-dependent, and so more of a programming question. Try computing `q->rear - q->front`.

Comment: Should I post the whole code ? Or ask It at stack overflow ?

Comment: If your question involves code then it belongs on stackoverflow.

Comment: No you just need to know the implementation details .

Comment: I don't understand the question. In a circular buffer, the number of elements in it can be computed in constant time. (It's basically the distance between the pointers, wrapping around and $\pm 1$.) (And that much doesn't seem to language dependent, @YuvalFilmus?)

Comment: Here is a link for the circular queue so you always cannot do front -rear .http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/circular-queue-set-1-introduction-array-implementation/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose that the queue consists of elements $Q[a],\ldots,Q[b]$, where $Q = Q[1],\ldots,Q[n]$ is an array of length $n$. If $a \leq b$ then the queue contains $b-a+1$ elements, and if $a > b$ then the queue contains $b-a+1+n$ elements.

Comment: How can queue contain more than n elements ?

Comment: It doesn't contain more than $n$ elements. I encourage you to try some example such as $a=n$ and $b=1$. The queue in this case contains $b-a+1+n = 2$ elements, $Q[n]$ and $Q[1]$.

Comment: 10 Appended
20 Appended
30 Appended
40 Appended
50 Appended
10 Removed
20 Removed
60 Appended
70 Appended
30 Removed
40 Removed
80 Appended
90 Appended
Queue Size:5
Position:4  Element:50
Position:5  Element:60
Position:0  Element:70
Position:1  Element:80
Position:2  Element:90  Now here the front is at 4 and rear is at 2

Comment: My indices start at 1. You'll have to figure out on your own what changes (if anything) when the indices start at 0.

Comment: Can we apply these formulas ?

Comment: Take it as a challenge.